# Cannot open .jpg or .png files all of a sudden when using Chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

All of a sudden I'm getting errors when I save *jpeg* or *png* files with *Google Chrome* on Ubuntu, then try to open them.

If I use *Firefox*, saving the images to Desktop and opening them is NOT a problem.

I've tried several different websites just to make sure it's not the website. I've also asked others to open it on their computers (with Ubunutu installed) and they said it opened fine (of course, I forgot to ask if they were using Chrome at the time).

Here is the error I get when trying to open the file:

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x52 0x49)
```

when I run the `file` command on several different files form different sites:

```
file Verlag_Poster_Large_23.jpg
Verlag_Poster_Large_23.jpg: RIFF (little-endian) data

file R-2153295-1287083265.jpeg.jpg
R-2153295-1287083265.jpeg.jpg: RIFF (little-endian) data

file cover.jpg
cover.jpg: RIFF (little-endian) data
```

*edit: Not 100% yet, but I think it was the Wappalyzer extension*. I "reloaded" it and now it's fine but will keep it watched.

Comment: Can you run the command `file the-jpg-that-gives-the-error.jpg` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: No problem, added output of file command.

Comment: It seems that this image is not a valid JPEG image. It is most like a chunk of file, not the whole file (you can read more about [RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format)). 

For some reason chrome is not downloading the whole image or maybe you did not waited the download to finish? Do you have any plugins? Also from where did you install Google Chrome? Which version are you using?

Comment: It does it to ALL files I save with Chrome. I am most definitely waiting for the file to complete. It's weird, it's been doing it for a little while but now it's all the time. Is there anything in my "user data" that I can clear out? I think Chrome is running out of space or something. Of course, I could be totally wrong about this. I'll get back to you on those questions shortly.

Comment: Ok after you answer previous questions can you also post the output of this command in the question `df -h` and also tell me where are you downloading the files? On your home partition or on external hard drive? If it is home partition if you have an usb drive can you plug it in and try to download to it with "Save As" option. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I"m sorry. I didn't mean my hard drive. I have plenty of room. I was referring more to something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481774/chrome-unstable-in-14-04?rq=1 I seem to have some errors going on there 1) Yes, I have plenty of plug-ins installed. 2) I installed the right when I installed Ubuntu, I think it was straight from www.google.com/chrome. 3) Version is: Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit)

Comment: Can you try disabling all of the plugins and download something again? AFAIK chrome 41 is the latest version for ubuntu atm.

Comment: Wow, once I did  `--disable-extensions` and went to discogs I can download and view jpegs with no issues. So it's a plug-in causing this issue? If so, now to find which one. :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes it seems like it is. I will post this as answer. Glad I helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After short investigation it seems like the files never finished the downlod process completely and was left as chunks.

Disabling all chrome plugins seems to fix the problem, it is up to the author to find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Actually you just rename the file from `.jpg`/`.png` to `.webp` and you should be able to open it in a browser

Answer (score 26):

Actually, if the file starts with "0x52 0x49", then it's a .webp image. Just replace the file name extension from 'jpg' or 'jpeg' with 'webp'. If you'd like to convert it to a 'jpg' or 'png' then open it with something like [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) and re-save the image in the desired format.

P.S. Yes I know this question is old but it's the first in the list of answers so it should have the correct information.

Regards, Professor Techie

Comment: This should be an accepted answer.

Comment: gimp appears unable to open `.webp` files ... i get this message: "failed: Unknown file type"

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me. I renamed the extension to webp, opened it in GIMP and exported it as a jpg.

Comment: That is right, is a webp format! 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP

ImageMagick is abled for it, but first install webp libraries (I use Debian but tested at Ubuntu 180.04)

sudo apt install webp

After use:

convert file_image.webp file_image.png

More options:
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/webp.php